# How to write Newton-Raphson module and return a value?

Tags: equation-solving, nonlinear

I am writing a code which solve nonlinear algebraic systems via Newton-Raphson algorithm. I want to make a Newton Module with another file and use the Module in my test file, but i didn't achieve it. Because, If the method is not converged, I break the code and return "not converged". Hence, iteration is not continuing and my code is not working properly. Here is my code:

```
F[y1_,y2_] = {
((y1 - 11)^2 / 64) - ((y2-7)^2/100) -1,
(y1-3)^2 + (y2-1)^2 -400
}; (*Define nonlinear algebraic system vector *)

J[y1_,y2_] = Outer[D,F[y1,y2],{y1,y2}]; (* Find symbolic jacobian *)

{y10,y20}= {20,-4}; (* Initial values for newton iterations *)

Tol   = 10^-12;
counter = 0; (*How many newton iterations*)
DeltaY = {0.1,0.1};
MaxIter = 50;
list  = Table[{0,0},{i,1,MaxIter}];
(* Begin loop for newton iterations *)
i=1;
While[Norm[ DeltaY, 2] > Tol,
    Result = Solve[J[y10,y20].{{dy1},{dy2}}==-F[y10,y20],{dy1,dy2}] //N //Flatten ;  (*Solve linear system for Delta y *)
    DeltaY = {dy1,dy2}/.Result;
    {y10,y20} = {y10,y20} + DeltaY; (*Find new Y values with computed delta y solutions *)
    list[[i]] = {y10,y20}; (* Append new computed Y elements into list array *)
    Print[list[[i]]," and error:",DeltaY]       
    Print[Norm[ DeltaY, Infinity]]
    If[i>MaxIter,Print["Not converged"] Return[{0,0}];]
counter++
i++;
] //AbsoluteTiming
```

How can I make `n` dimensional newton iteration module without breaking code. Also how to return a value with a module.

Note: I will use my newton module for some implicit numerical schemes.

Best regards.

Comment: Sorry, Newton.m is including just a function

Jac[f_, x_] := Outer[D, f, x];

Comment: Ok, then please change the code, and just define the function in the code. The idea is to allow one to run the code.

Comment: Ok @Nasser. I did it. Now you can run the code in your computer.

Comment: Mean while, the API to the function should be very clear: What is the input to the function should be, and what is the output. how will you be calling it?  What is should return?

Comment: I will give the parameters which are

Function,Jacobian,Max Iteration, Error Tolerance, Dimension. Our module will seems like
NewtonMethod[Function,Jacobian,Max Iteration, Error Tolerance, Dimension] = Solution vector or false

Comment: Your code certainly runs and produces results, although I have not verified their accuracy.  For clarity, are you simply trying to convert the code into a `Module`, or something else?  Also, are you certain that `FindRoot` will not meet your needs?

Comment: My friend @bbgodfrey, I couldn't convert my above code into a Module. I have already ask how can i do it?. FindRoot will meet my needs but i want to control everything while solving a problem. 

Briefly, I want to write an implicit Runge-Kutta package with Mathematica like this matlab script  https://bitbucket.org/drreynolds/rklab. If I achieve this, I can publish a paper or book to help people about numerical computations on implicit methods via Mathematica. 

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MichaelE2 it's [Module](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Module.html)

Comment: Since you plan to use this and it's not just an exercise, why not use the built-in Newton's method function, `FindRoot`?

Comment: Dear @MichaelE2, as I say above, I want to control everything in my iteration scheme. FindRoot is written by another person. If I want to add something to FindRoot method, I think I can not do it. So, I want to write my own code from zero to hero ;)

Comment: I see.  (BTW, `FindRoot` does everything you mention you want to do in the question.  You can use `Check` to see if it complains about convergence. There are also the options `EvaluationMonitor` and `StepMonitor`, from which you can `Throw` exceptions.  `FindRoot` does do some other things automatically or mysteriously, like check step size, so I can understand if you want to write your own. )

Comment: Thank you everybody for useful comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest code to create your module is

```
nr[func_, jac_, y1_, y2_, MaxIter_, Tol_] := 
 Module[{y10 = y1, y20 = y2, counter = 0, DeltaY = {0.1, 0.1}, 
   list = Table[{0, 0}, {i, 1, MaxIter}], i = 1},
  While[Norm[DeltaY, 2] > Tol, 
   Result = Solve[jac[y10, y20].{{dy1}, {dy2}} == -func[y10, y20], {dy1, 
        dy2}] // N // Flatten;
   DeltaY = {dy1, dy2} /. Result;
   {y10, y20} = {y10, y20} + DeltaY;
   list[[i]] = {y10, y20};
   Print[list[[i]], " and error:", DeltaY, "  ", i, "  ", counter] ;
   Print[Norm[DeltaY, Infinity]]; 
   If[i > MaxIter, Print["Not converged"] Return[{0, 0}];] ;
   counter++ ;
   i++;]; {y10, y20}]
```

Call it with

```
nr[F, J, y10, y20, MaxIter, Tol]
```

and it will produce the `Print` statements produced by the code in your question, plus the answer, `{22.519, -3.35977}`.  Of course, your final product should contain options, documentation, additional error checks, and the like.  Hope this helps.

Comment: It works now. But i will do some modifications and will publish the code here. Thank you ;)

Comment: @bbgodfrey: It would be great if it could do it for functions of general $n$ dimensional size. However, even being able to add 3D examples like $f(x,y,z)$ would be great as it currently only supports @D examples $f(x,y)$.

Comment: @drxy I am leaving soon on a trip and shall not be able to think about this for several days.  Sorry.

Comment: @bbgodfrey friend its amzoti's comment. I will try to solve his problem. Thank you. Good luck at your job.

Answer (score 4):

Why not make use of *Mathematica* built-in functional capabilities?  The following code can be modified to add whatever stopping condition is desired.

```
   jac[f_, vars_] := Outer[D, f[Sequence @@ vars], vars]
   jacobian[f_, vars_, pt_] := jac[f, vars] /. Thread[vars -> pt]
   newt[f_, vars_, pt_] := pt - Inverse[jacobian[f, vars, pt]].f[Sequence @@ pt]

   f[x_, y_] := {x y - 3, x^2 + y^2 - 9}
   NestList[newt[f, {x, y}, #] &, {3., 1.}, 5]

(*
    {{3.,1.},{2.8125,1.0625},{2.80256,1.07042},{2.80252,1.07047},{2.80252,1.07047},{2.80252,1.07047}}
*)
```

Comment: Dear @murray, your way is highly efficient. But I am lack of functional programming now. I will work Mathematica's  functional ways if I find an appropriate time. Thank you very much.